# pinTintColor compatibility

Tags: ios, mapkit, uicolor

I understand that I can now have the pins in all the colors I want using pintintcolor in iOS 9.  What is the compatibility? WIll I be able to use this with ios 8 as I am compiling on ios 9 with earliest target being ios 8?

Answer (score -1):

> WIll I be able to use this with ios 8

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPinAnnotationView/pinTintColor):

> ```
> pinTintColor
> ```
>
> **Property**
>
> The color of the pin head.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 9.0 and later.

Is iOS 8 "iOS 9.0 and later"? Ask yourself. No, it isn't. So, no, you won't be able to use `pinTintColor` with iOS 8. Your code may compile (if you are using Objective-C), but you'll crash if the `pinTinColor` property is encountered on iOS 8.

The way one typically supplies other pin colors (beyond red, green, and purple) in iOS 8 and before is supply your own pin artwork.

Comment: (Another good reason for using Swift, which will actively stop you from making this kind of mistake.)

Comment: Agree. Am using Swift for any new project. That one using MKmapkit is an iOS 3 app which I maintained and improved till iOS 6 and now am improving it with iOS 9. 

Shame that I can't mix objective c and swift within the same *.m file

Comment: "Shame that I can't mix objective c and swift within the same *.m file" Not in the same file, but you can certainly mix them within the same _class_.